# Is there way to secure the import api using laravel passport token and ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have confusing thinking on importing of ajax, for me this is not secured way to import the ajax api request for login of user. i just import the ajax api of user to the end of the body of html. I will show you the example of my import structure of ajax.

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
</head>
<body>



<script src="{{ asset('fullcalendar-4.4.0/packages/core/main.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('fullcalendar-4.4.0/packages/interaction/main.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('fullcalendar-4.4.0/packages/daygrid/main.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('fullcalendar-4.4.0/packages/timegrid/main.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/users_api.js') }}" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Question: Is that safe to import there? or is there another way to not show the script source of api?

Comment: what is users_api.js?

Comment: is a calling of api request. storing of token to session storage to check if valid user or not.

Comment: I don't see how a fixed asset could be by itself a security risk without seeing the content first

Comment: it's a function of login user.